# Want to write a code in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I want to write a code in Jquery in a such a way that whenever a string is inserted it will  automatically put a space in between.For e.g "StockExchange" is there then it will show it as "Stock Exchange".Another way to explain is whenever a Capital letter is encountered second time in the same string it will provide a space in between.
I am new in Coding,Kindly help.
Thank You.

Comment: what about iPhone and iPad?

Comment: @zzlalani No matter, I think he can't code HTML too

Answer (score 1):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uXy64/128/)

```
var str="StackExchange"
alert(str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "SpiderCode";

var updatedName = name.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
alert(updatedName);

// Output : Spider Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look on this... It will help you surely.

```
s = s.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Dd8RY/